# If I upload a text file via one form, is it possible to read it on other form that is showing record of a particular entries from database?

Tags: php, file

I don't want to read file using `tmp_name`. Is there any other possible methods to read file from a folder with its original name that I stored in databases?

Also, I am trying to access contents of that file in second form.

Comment: i am new to php so apologies if i asked in a wrong way

Answer (score 0):

All else being equal: No.

A file was uploaded and it was saved to a temporary place with a generated filename and your PHP program was told what filename the client said it should have. The two filenames are not the same.

You can't access it using its original file name because that isn't the file name it has on the computer running the PHP.

The script handling the upload *could* use `move_uploaded_file` to move the file to somewhere else and change its name so it is the same as the one the client told you it originally had. Then you would be able to use that name. You would, of course, have to be careful to avoid collisions. Two different files with the same name could be uploaded.